# Aggregating date data by calendar month

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have some data which relates to users signing up to a system, and when they disabled their account (for simplicity I have just written the year/month):

```
name  | created   | deactivated
------|-----------|--------------
Dan   | 2018 / 2  | 2018 / 5
Mike  | 2018 / 4  | 2018 / 7 
Dave  | 2018 / 5  | NULL
```

How would I write a query that transformed this data into an aggregate form based on the calendar months, dating back to the start of the year, for example:

```
month     | created  | deactivated
----------|----------|--------------
2018 / 7  | 0        | 1
2018 / 6  | 0        | 0
2018 / 5  | 1        | 1
2018 / 4  | 1        | 0
2018 / 3  | 0        | 0
2018 / 2  | 1        | 0
2018 / 1  | 0        | 0
```

I have been able to come up with something like this for a single column:

```
SELECT
  extract(year from created) || ' / ' || extract(month from created) as month,
  count('month')
FROM accounts
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

But then I become stuck around how to then add another column based on another field (I am using `created` in the `GROUP BY`). This query will also omit months that don't contain any data, and wont go back to `2018 / 1` when there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that `month` is really a date.  If so, use `generate_series()` to generate the dates and then `left join` and `group by` to do the calculations:

```
select gs.mon, sum(created) as created, sum(deactivated) as deactivated
from generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2018-07-01'::date, interval '1 month') gs(mon) left join
     ((select created as dte, 1 as created, 0 as deactivated 
       from accounts
      ) union all
      (select deactivated, 0 as created, 1 as deactivated 
       from accounts
      )
     ) a
     on date_trunc('month', a.dte) = gs.mon
group by gs.mon;
```